# TableView calculates wrong height for dynamic width&height label

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I've read multiple threads about this but I've found no solution yet.

I'm making a chat-like application

---

The app has a **TableView** that has **dynamic height cells** in it.

A cell consists of a **view** and a **multiline label** in it.

If the label has more characters than **>250** it gets shortened with an ending **"... see more"**

---

Now the problem is that sometimes the label gets cut off.

I played a little with the `Line Break` setting of the label, and after changing it to **Character Wrap** the label shows its full text.

**Left picture**: `Character Wrap` - - - **Right picture:** `Word Wrap` (I need this)

[image]*As you see on the right picture, the "Bt... See More" gets cut off..*

---

I realised that if I set the **label's width** or the **view's width** to a fixed size then the problem gets solved: So maybe the problem's root is in the bubble view's leading constraint:

```
Align leading to Superview
Constant: 0
Priority: 1000
Multiplier: 0.25
```

(This is needed so that the bubble view expands maximum to 75% of the superview)

I made a GitHub repo for this:

https://github.com/krptia/chatBubbleTest

**Help please!**

---

Anyone?

Comment: i suggest you to use manual calculation for best performance or you can use hight caching mechanism which give you average performance

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer, not as part of the question. Or else delete the question so it doesn’t go on sitting here.

Comment: What happens if you fix the width? Currently they have variable width. Set it to a fixed width just to try.

Comment: @Fogmeister I tried that and setting a fixed width to the view or the label fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLUTION

I figured out that if I set the bubble view's leading constant the following:

```
Align leading to Superview
Constant: 0
Priority: 1000
Multiplier: 0.25
```

In order to set the maximum width to 75%, the label inside wraps incorrectly.

**SO I deletet the leading constraint and instead of that I maximize the width via aspect-ratio!**

If I use **aspect-ratio** ***2:3***

Then I achieve the same outcome, but with the label wrapping correctly!!

Yay

## SOLUTION 2.0

Okay, now I have figured out that the bubble view's leading constraint's second item (SuperView.Trailing) was **Relative to Margin**

After unchecking it, the problem gets fixed, so I don't have to use aspect ratio! Yay

## BUT PAY ATTENTION

Because using `Line Break: Word Wrap` also causes some problems.

Sometimes it tries to break the text into a new line (minimum 2 words) but if the cell was reused then the app might calculate wrong height for the view.

---

**First picture**: `Word Wrap` - - - - - - - **Second picture**: `Clip`

[image]

Maybe this issue can be fixed with layoutIfNeeded() or i don't know. Clip is fine for me

## UPDATE (2019.03.27)

Umm.. I realised that the problem occurs still... I don't understand why.

Still trying to figure it out..